# Swap two objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, swap

I have the following code:

```
MyObject.prototype.doIt = function()
{
     var a = this.obj1;
     var b = this.obj2; 
}
```

How can i swap the values of **this.obj1** and **this.obj2** so obj1 becomes obj2 and obj2 becomes obj1.

**!Note: Have in mind that i am not working with primitive types.**

Answer (score 17):

You can swap any number of objects or literals, even of different types, using a simple identity function like this:

```
var swap = function (x){return x};
b = swap(a, a=b);
c = swap(a, a=b, b=c);
```

This works in JavaScript because it accepts additional arguments even if they are not declared or used.  The assignments `a=b` etc, happen after `a` is passed into the function.

Comment: using this but like: `const swap = x => x;`

Answer (score 5):

We can use about the destructing objects, like below code:

```
let a = 2;
let b = 4;
[a, b] = [b, a];
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a temporary variable to hold the contents of one of the objects while swapping:

```
var tmp = this.obj1;
this.obj1 = this.obj2;
this.obj2 = tmp;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can swap the properties easily enough:

```
MyObject.prototype.doIt = function()
{
     var a = this.obj1;
     var b = this.obj2;
     this.obj1 = b;
     this.obj2 = a;
}
```

That `obj1` and `obj2` are not primitive types is irrelevant. You don't actually need two variables:

```
MyObject.prototype.doIt = function()
{
     var a = this.obj1;
     this.obj1 = this.obj2;
     this.obj2 = a;
}
```

However, if any references to `this.obj1` or `this.obj2` already exist outside this code, they won't be swapped.

In terms of swapping `this.obj1` and `this.obj2` everywhere (including existing references), I don't think that can be done completely. You could strip out all properties of, say, `this.obj1` (saving them somewhere), add in the properties from `this.obj2`, and then do the same for `this.obj2`. However, you won't be able to swap the prototypes, so objects cannot fundamentally swap identities.

Comment: In fact, you _could_ swap prototype with the use of `Object.getPrototypeOf()` and `Object.setPrototypeOf()`, but [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) strongly warn us it's a really bad idea for the application performance.

Comment: @FélixBrunet - Hadn't thought about that. I guess it is possible to implement something like [Smalltalk's `become:` method](https://gbracha.blogspot.com/2009/07/miracle-of-become.html). Cool!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with concrete objects, say your original objects are 2 divs, div1 and div2.

To swap them,

var temp1 = div1;
var temp2 = div2;

div1 = temp2;
div2 = temp1;